# How to ping a web server in Python 3.10

Tags: python, operating-system, ping, icmp

Alrighty, time to ask a very stupid/obvious question. I need to ping a webserver/website to see if it's valid, using the ICMP protocol. You know...`ping facebook.com`. My code generates a bunch of TLD's, and subdomain's to a user-inputted domain name. I plan on pinging all of them (it's about 6 usually) to see if they're actually valid before doing what I need to do with them. However, all the tutorials and questions similar to mine are from like 2010 and don't work anymore. The one thing I have got to work printed out the results of the ping, which I don't want. So maybe some sort of function that like below, it just returns or prints out whether or not it's online not actual responses if that makes sense:

```
def website_checker():
     
     if os.system("ping facebook.com"):
           
          print("facebook.com is valid")
     
     else:
    
          print("facebook.com is not valid")
```

I'm not sure if that helps but I can't put it into any better words. Please, I'm pulling my hair out

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/icmplib/ - use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to the help of @Moanos! Here is the code:

```
from icmplib import ping

def host_up(hostname:str):
    host = ping(hostname, count=5, interval=0.2)
    return host.packets_sent == host.packets_received

hosts = "facebook.gov"

try:
    if host_up(hosts):
        print(f"{hosts} is valid")
except:
    print(f"{hosts} is not valid")
```

So to the function is @Moanos's code, but the rest is mine. The reason I am using a try, except block is to prevent the NameLookupError from printing out! So when it's valid, it says only that it's valid and same case for when it is not a valid domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ping lib to make the ping.

```
import ping, socket
try:
    ping.verbose_ping('www.google.com', count=3)
    delay = ping.Ping('www.wikipedia.org', timeout=2000).do()
except socket.error, e:
    print "Ping Error:", e
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [icmplib](https://pypi.org/project/icmplib/). The following code tries to ping `host` an returns `True` if the DNS lookup was successful and the host responds all pings.

```py
from icmplib import ping
from icmplib.exceptions import NameLookupError


def host_up(hostname: str):
    try:
        host = ping(hostname, count=5, interval=0.2, timeout=1, privileged=False)
    except NameLookupError:
        return False
    return host.packets_sent == host.packets_received


visit = "facebook.com"
if host_up(visit):
    print(f"{visit} is valid")
else:
    print(f"{visit} is not valid")
```

Comment: I got icmplib installed finally, it's a nice library. Your code does partially what I want, when the domain is valid it print's out that it is, but when it isn't then it throws out a bunch of results about how it cannot be resolved. Not simply ("Not valid"). Any advice? Thank you so so so much for your help! @Moanos

Comment: Yes, this was my mistake - when you input a domain name that can not be resolved icmplib throws a `NameLookupError`. I catch this now and you should have the expected result